# Confusion regarding Simple, Complex and Compound sentences

Tags: subordinate-clauses

My English teacher recently covered simple, complex and compound sentences in class. She told us that:

1. A simple sentence has one clause.
2. A compound sentence has two clauses.
3. A complex sentence has three clauses.

Quick research on the internet proved that either she was dead wrong or she was trying to teach me some "baby rules". I am very confused, and since I have my exam coming up I don't know what to do. I have tried to learn online but have found this to be quite a confusing topic. For example, how is this sentence a simple sentence:

*"Despite a lot of difficulties, we succeeded in reaching the base camp for the final trek."*

From what I have gathered, a simple sentence has one clause but this appears to have two. What is the basic definition of these three types of sentences? Am I going wrong somewhere? Any help with explaining this clearly and simply will be appreciated.

Comment: "The people who are poor deserve our support." What type of a sentence is this then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional definitions of simple, compound and complex sentences:

- A simple sentence has a single independent clause and no dependent (subordinate) clauses.
- A compound sentence has two or more independent clauses and no dependent clauses.
- A complex sentence has at least one independent clause and at least one dependent clause.

Only **clauses** are considered, not constituents of other sorts. In traditional grammar a clause must contain both a subject and a predicate.

> Despite a lot of difficulties, we succeeded in reaching the base camp for the final trek.

By the traditional standard, this sentence contains only one clause. *reaching the base camp* is not accepted as a "clause" because it contains no subject.

Some modern grammarians might accept the constituent headed by *reaching* as a clause from which the subject has been deleted; but modern grammarians are not usually interested in the categories ‘simple, compound, complex’—the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, for instance, observes in a footnote (page 45) that two given sentences might be distinguished as ‘simple vs complex clauses but no great significance attaches to this [...] distinction, and we shall not make further use of these terms.’

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyways, suppose I am given the sentence "Poor people deserve our support." and asked to transform it into complex, then I would have to make sure that the sentence would have one principal clause and another subordinate clause. So how can I achieve this without changing the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya "People who are poor deserve our support" or "Poor people are the ones who deserve our support" or "We should support people who are poor".

Comment: Since virtually all English sentences are complex, the other two categories are kind of irrelevant. It's rather like classifying numbers into _1, 2,_ and _Many_.

Comment: Where is the independent clause in "People who are poor deserve our support."?
@JohnLawler ikr. My school has this in its syllabus and it's so annoying.

Comment: The independent clause is _People [...] deserve our support._ The [...] part is the dependent relative clause _who are poor_ that modifies _people_.

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya I know of only one reason for learning the difference between simple, compound and complex sentences: to pass an exam on the difference between simple, compound and complex sentences.

Comment: @JohnLawler it's confusing but I think I understood that one. In the sentence `"Our teacher is the one who took us to the field."`, what is the independent clause? Is it `"Our teacher took us to the field."`? Then what's the subject in the dependent clause `"is the one who"`?

@StoneyB exactly.

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya The main clause is *Our teacher is the one*; its subject is *Our teacher. The subject of the subordinate relative clause *who took us to the field* is actually deleted, but *who* points to the 'gap' and assumes the subject role.